# How to get the click position on a page when a css zoom is involved

Tags: javascript, html, css

My current code is

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    console.log(event.pageX + "-" + event.pageY);
});
```

however, there is a zoom set on the body (although I've no control over it, sometimes it's not there) and event.pageX and event.pageY are coming out wrong.

Is there a way to get a relative value or something?

Edit:

The css on the body is

```
body {
    zoom: 0.485417;
}
```

The zoom value may change (as part of some external JS - I've no control over that value, my JS doesn't set it, and it can change)

Comment: This is a good question, seems that it have been reported as a bug for Edge, Chromium and Firefox. I'm not sure if it's a bug though.

Comment: Maybe this will help >> https://github.com/tombigel/detect-zoom

After detecting zoom you can count difference between original window.width and zoomed width and add or substract this difference from click position

Comment: Can you include the `css` at Question?

Comment: @Paul You might be able to read the zoom though: `getComputedStyle(document.body).zoom`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I nailed this with the help of andlrc's comment:

```
var zoomLevel = getComputedStyle(document.body).zoom;
if (zoomLevel <= 0) { zoomLevel = 0.1; }
doMyThing(event.pageX / zoomLevel, event.pageY / zoomLevel);
```

x and y passed in to "doMyThing" is now properly positioned, regardless of what the zoom is set to.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving zoom value to body, give zoom value to a top div under the body.

ie:

```
<style>.zoom-this{zoom:85%}</style>

<body>
<div class='zoom-this'>
      Blabla content
</div>
</body>
```