# Click event when css zoom is applied to the body - chrome update

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

On a web application, I need to get the coordinates of the mouse click. On  my page, I apply a zoom of 0.8 to the body `body{ zoom: 0.8;}` when the width is lesser than 400px.

The click event has/had a feature where if zoom was applied to the body, the coordinates weren't correct (as seen on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37173278/how-to-get-the-click-position-on-a-page-when-a-css-zoom-is-involved)), so, we need to compensate the zoom by doing

```
var coordX = event.clientX / zoom;
var coordY = event.clientY / zoom;
```

Now, with one of the newer updates of the Chrome (I can't figure out the exact version, but on the 94 this is true) it seems that the click event takes in consideration the zoom property, which means, the previous code I had `var coordX = event.clientX / zoom;` is wrong.

The problem is that I can't find any documentation that can corroborate my theory.

So, if I change my code, I know it will work for those who has the latest version of Chrome and it will not work on previous versions. But because I can't be sure that my theory is correct (without documentation proving it) I'm a little concerned on updating based on a "hunch".

Can anyone confirm my suspicions?